# NXT uses transparent forging to detect who will solve the blocks. How can DDOS be prevented?

Tags: nxt, forging

Since NXT does transparent forging and it select a node to be the main one to solve blocks. How does it prevent a DDOS attack? And if a ddos was sucessful on the node during forging, what happens then? does it solve blocks half way only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transparent Forging tells where to send transactions to but it doesn't force to use the same node for generation of blocks. In the worst case the next block will be empty. Empty blocks still secure the blockchain with already included transactions.

Comment: Why are blocks forged if there are no transactions?

Comment: Empty blocks increase cumulative difficulty of the blockchain and doesn't allow to fork it.

Comment: Difficulty?  I thought NXT was 100% PoS.  Please explain.  (as i look for src...)

Comment: Blockchain technology requires a way to choose the best branch. "Difficulty" is a term used in PoW currencies, it shows how it's difficult to generate a block. Nxt uses an analogy that every coin is a virtual mining rig, and "difficulty" is one of the terms borrowed from Bitcoin. In Nxt higher difficulty of a branch means that this particular branch was forged by owners of a larger amount of coins.

Comment: Hmm, I like the way you guys do that.

Answer (score 3):

I am a developer for NXT and am currently programming an automated defense system for the network, aside from this if a forger is DDOS'd my understanding is that the network will skip to the next node and not process the block the attacked node produce(s/d).

Comment: Yes, it does skip.  What happens if an attacker could DDoS each subsequent node since they can be known by all with high certainty?